# Working with firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP in Python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have stored "dates" in firestore using `firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP`

When I retrieve this value and print it, I get the following:

`<object object at 0x7f5f4b30eaa0>`

What is the right way to format this?

Comment: Can you give a code snippet showing how you retrieve and print the above value?

Comment: Yes. I create an object  `publication_collection = publication_ref.get().to_dict()` and then I print the value previously created using firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP from the object  `publication_collection['date_checked']`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried the following code, and I get the result back as a Python `datetime` object:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate('./public/scripts/cert.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
client = firestore.client()
client.collection('test').document('foo').set({
    'mytime':firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP
})

data = client.collection('test').document('foo').get().to_dict()
print 'Full object:', data
print 'Timestamp:', data['mytime']
```

Output:

```
Full object: {u'mytime': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 6, 19, 17, 55, 31000, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
Timestamp: 2018-07-06 19:17:55.031000+00:00
```

Tested on Python 2.7 with latest Admin SDK.

Comment: Great. It returns a datetime object.